# Eliminar * y organizar frases en C++

Tags: c++, programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo que hacer un programa cuya función sea hacer que este texto previamente guardado con una variable, salga por la pantalla con este estilo.

Cuando el texto tiene una `/`, debe haber un salto de línea. Formando un poema.
No se como empezar ¿Alguna ayuda?

Ejemplo:
`***estaba**mar****serena*la/**estaba****mar*serena***la/*****calma***mar**serena*mar****en/*la***esconde**calma*****pesar****un/**el******olas*****tus*por***seno****de/***lágrimas****van**de*olas/*****oculta*cuando****se**la***luna/**oculta*se*****mar****la***allende/**mar*temes****nunca***que*****vuelva/****sideral*de**su***viaje/***luna**suspiras****vuelve*y/****ya*vuelve**vuelve***vuelve.`

Salida:

> ```
> la mar estaba serena
> serena estaba la mar 
> mar serena mar en calma 
> tu calma esconde un pesar 
> por el seno de tus olas 
> olas de lágrimas van 
> cuando la luna se oculta 
> se oculta allende la mar 
> temes mar que nunca vuelva 
> de su viaje sideral 
> y suspiras luna vuelve 
> vuelve vuelve vuelve ya
> ```

Aqui dejo mi codigo:

```C
#include <stdio.h>
    #define FINAL   '.'
    #define MAXCAR  100 //Por poner algo
    #define MAXPAR  100 //Por poner algo

    /*1r nivell*/
    void inicialitza_variables();
    void demanar_dades();
    void obtenir_seguent_paraula();
    int final_seq();
    void tractar_paraula();
    void sortida_pantalla();
    /*2n nivell*/
    void saltar_asterics();//Es como el saltar blancs pero en asterics

    struct paraules{
    char caracter[MAXCAR];
    };

    struct frases{
    struct paraules frase[MAXPAR];
    int ultima;
    };

    int main(void)
    {
    int index=0;

    inicialitza_variables();
    demanar_dades();
    obtenir_seguent_paraula();

    while(!final_seq()){
        tractar_paraula();
        obtenir_seguent_paraula();
    }
    sortida_pantalla();
    }

    int final_seq(){
    return(caracter[index]==FINAL);
    }

    //SEGON NIVELL DISSENY DESCENDENT
    void saltar_asterics()
    {
    while(cad[*index]=='*'){
        *index=*index+1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: "*No se como empezar, alguna ayuda??*". Empieza con `int main() {`.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Empieza con hacer un bucle que con la variable previamente definida vea con un switch que hacer con su repectivo caso. Una pista: switch(var[i]){ case '*': continue; }

Comment: A dia de hoy tengo esto programada, pero no se como seguir!! #include <stdio.h> #define FINAL '.' #define MAXCAR 100 //Por poner algo #define MAXPAR 100 //Por poner algo /*1r nivell*/ void inicialitza_variables(); void demanar_dades(); void obtenir_seguent_paraula(); int final_seq(); void tractar_paraula(); void sortida_pantalla(); /*2n nivell*/ void saltar_asterics();//Es como el saltar blancs pero en asterics struct paraules{ char caracter[MAXCAR]; }; struct frases{ struct paraules frase[MAXPAR]; int ultima; }; int main(void) { int index=0; inicialitza_variables(); demanar_dades(); obtenir_s

Comment: @Pablochaches ahora mismo el codigo programada que tengo es este

Comment: @DanielBriceño pero un switch para que me sirve en este caso, un menú no creo que deba hacer

Comment: Pregunta:¿ La variable caracter es grobal?

Comment: @DanielCalle Los switch no solo sirven para hacer menus. Sirven para evitar hacer esto: if(variable==1){}else if(variable==2){}else if(variable==3){} else if(variable==4){}else{} Para no repetir el nombre de la variable por cada condicion, los que diseñaron el lenguaje isieron esto: switch(variable){case 1:break;case 2;break;case 3:break;case 4:break;default:}

Comment: ¿De donde salen las variables????????. En la funcion saltar_alterisco deberia pasarle por algumento la variable index de main:  void saltar_alterisco(int* index,char* cad);. Tambien en la funcion final_seq deberia pasar variables, porque las variables index y caracter no son globales: int final_seq(int index,char* caracter);

Comment: Tampoco inicializas una variable caracter en main. Y si la  inicializas en inicialitza_variables() no sobrevivirá al terminar esa funcion. Tienes o ya sea declarar la variable global o pasarla por puntero para poder inicializarla: int main(){ char caracter[MAXCAR];inicialitza_variables(caracter);.......} void inicialitza_variables(char* caracter);

Comment: Vaaaas. Tampoco se que hace la funcion tractar_paraula() o obtenir_seguent_paraula().

Comment: Pero este codigo ya es un comienzo. Intenta arreglar los errores y continuamos con este problema.

Comment: Y ¿como te va?.